# Hide Bootstrap tab in drop down menu when it wraps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a custom tab control based on classic Boostrap's `nav-tabs`. Last tab is menu, dropdown with all tabs that cannot  be fitted to the page. I have an idea how to hide tab and add it to this menu - just handling `onresize` event and check `ul.nav-tabs` height. Once it doubles - it means that last tab with text must be hidden and moved to menu.

I have a problen with detecting on resize whether window have enough width to reveal one or more tabs from menu?

Maybe exists javascript plugin for that? I do not want to calculate manually all widths and based on this value detect space, maybe there is easier way?

[image]

Comment: At 3700+ points, you should know the rules of asking a question here; two of which are (1) Show your work and what you've tried if you want help, and (2) Don't ask for help finding libraries/plugins.

Comment: I am confused as to what you're asking.